# PKPassLibrary containsPass return wrong value

Tags: ios, ios7, ios6, passbook

I add a PKPass to the library through `PKAddPassesViewController`.
The pass is visible in the passbook app.

The following code is called:

```
NSData *data = [NSData dataWithContentsOfFile:filePath];
NSError *error;

//init a pass object with the data
PKPass *pass = [[PKPass alloc] initWithData:data error:&error];

if([self.passbookLibrary containsPass:pass]) {
```

passbookLibrary is not nil.

containsPass returns YES on iOS7

containsPass returns NO on iOS6

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are two types of PKPass. PKLocalPass and PKRemotePass. The above created PKPass will be a PKLocalPass. The check only works with PKRemotePass. You can obtain it with this function:

```
- (PKPass *)passFromLibraryFromPKPass:(PKPass *)pass {
    if (SYSTEM_VERSION_LESS_THAN(@"7.0")) {
        PKPass *libraryPass = [self.passbookLibrary passWithPassTypeIdentifier:pass.passTypeIdentifier serialNumber:pass.serialNumber];
        return libraryPass;
    } else {
        return pass;
    }
}
```

Furthermore, the provisioning profile must be Passbook enabled. I created a new profile where with the App ID contains the pass type identifier.

iOS 7 is very nice in this context. It just works.